# How to enter a message on discord message text box via bot, discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Is there a method for pasting a text on the discord message text box where the user types text? I tried searching but couldn't find any. Is it possible?

Here's a message create event listener:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content === "random") {
        message.pastetotextbox(
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat"
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean a discord modal?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JsQo.png)

````
message.reply("```Text Here```");
````

or

````
message.channel.send("```Text Here```");
````

or if you don't want the text in box form;

```
message.reply("Text Here");
```

or

```
message.channel.send("Text Here");
```

would do this correctly.

Comment: If you read the OP question, it's asking for a input of some sort; not a message reply or code block.